# Does it make sense to keep the tag 'jobs'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag '[jobs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/jobs)' seems to be used a lot for questions around the role of UX, skills and career-development (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs). This tag might even encourage these type of questions, which I understand are not really appropriate for ux.stackexchange.com.

I can't think of a question that I would tag with 'jobs', maybe except for the type of things you would find on a website in some category 'jobs'.

So, should we

- remove the tag (and also review the older questions with this tag) *or*
- change the description in a way that might even help to prevent bad use or bad questions[2]

[2]can't think of a good description right now and also I am not sure if users really pay attention to tag descriptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I vote to remove it along with the [employment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment). I think any legitimate [jobs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) questions would also have the [career-development](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) tag which will encourage questions more in line with the values of the site.

Comment: I agree. Career development is on-topic, but basic jobs are not. There is a jobs/careers SE site, I think, which is probably more appropriate for that.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat most of these [jobs] questions here aren't on topic for The Workplace either, but I'm all for killing the tag.

Comment: I wasn't sure on the workplace, but I reckoned that adjusted question for there might work. Or some completely different site. If it is dead, then people will have to look for other places. I only thought that other sites might be better, and we can focus on the practice, rather than the career aspects!

Comment: @SchroedingersCat no no, [workplace.se] is still alive, I just meant I killed the employment tag.

Comment: @BenBrocka Ah Ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Employment tag. I'm considering merging [jobs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) with [career-development]. If the questions really, truly require UX/ect expertise, they seem acceptable for here. The "jobs" tag seems to only really be used for this purpose, not job offers/ect

Comment: There is also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field - similar to http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development ?

Comment: @user12999 honestly ux-field is a bit of a wildcard. Perhaps worth a separate question, it's not *entirely* a synonym of anything else

Comment: Agree, sounds pretty wide...